# show list of records chosen by a category in a category tree on a separate page

Tags: typo3, categories

TYPO3 11.5.12, events2 8.0.1

I get the used categories of a calendar (`https://www.my-domain.de/lehre/kalender`) in a category tree with the following fluid

```
<ul>
    <f:for each="{selectorData.categories.main}" as="category" iteration="catIterator">
        <li>
            <a href="{f:uri.page(pageUid: '{data.pid}', additionalParams: '{tx_events2_searchresults: {search: {mainCategory: \'{category.uid}\'}, controller: \'Search\', action: \'listSearchResults\'}}')}">{category.title}</a>
        </li>
    </f:for>
</ul>
```

After clicking on a category I want to show all records that are related to this category on a separate page (`https://www.my-domain.de/lehre/kalender/filter`). Right now, the URL changes to `https://www.my-domain.de/lehre/kalender/name-of-the-category` and the list of the events is the same. What plugin has to be inserted on the page `filter` and what do I have to do that the chosen category for the selection of the records is used on the page `filter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult in TYPO3 (or in general) to combine data from several tables in the URL.
Therefore the most simple and reliable approach is to create for each category a distinct page, there you can likely limit the output from events2 to the one category only (Sorry, I never used events2,so I never know for 100%).

Comment: Thank you for the pragmatic suggestion. It is a possible solution, but needs maintenance as soon as e.g. new categories are added.

Comment: yes right, and it would perhaps change the structure of your URLs too.

Comment: It's getting more complicated too if you consider this viewhelper: https://docs.typo3.org/p/jweiland/events2/main/en-us/AdministratorManual/Templates/ViewHelpers/GetAllowedCategoriesViewHelper.html which respects several categories